# Concurrent HashMap vs DynamoDb for cost, performance, and complexity

Tags: java, spring-boot, concurrency, amazon-dynamodb, scalability

I am writing an application that will only have around 10k - 100k requests per 24 hours. The application requires maintaining many maps, which totally will be about 3-4GB in size. These maps will be concurrently read and also written to, which through my own testing I believe I've handled just fine using SpringBoot, ConcurrentHashMap, and @RestController/@Service etc etc.

My question is, have I "done something wrong" by not using DynamoDb in this scenario? I will summarize some of my feelings about the pros and cons below:

**Data Size**

I can imagine that if I had TBs of data, DynamoDB would be a compelling choice here because such a large amount of data cannot fit comfortably into RAM without paying quite the price :) But 3-4GB of data can fit quite cheaply into an EC2 instance's RAM, and I'm not planning to have 100s of EC2 instances.

**Performance**

Not sure what could possibly be faster than an in-process ConcurrentHashMap for a REST application? Even if DynamoDB does in fact deliver millisecond latency, you still are making a network call.

**Complexity**

While the AWS SDK is a very common dependency to need anyway, and the DynamoDB API is quite friendly, the fact remains that there is a bit more complexity added to your application when using it compared to just a ConcurrentHashMap

**Cost**

This seems to me to be the principal reason for me to not use DynamoDb in my case. With a few EC2 instances running 24/7 with all of the data loaded into memory, I can have the best possible performance and least complex deployment process for a few hundred dollars per year? I am confident that these few EC2 instances can handle the read/write traffic I described above. And even if they couldn't, DynamoDB's capacity units also get very cost prohibitive as well very quickly.

EDIT: I should have mentioned that these maps are essentially configuration files and not anything that needs serious consistency/persistence guarantees like customer data or etc.

Comment: Do you need persistence? You're considering running for years with a data structure that's only held in memory?

Comment: Ah, I should have specified, these maps are essentially just configuration. I plan to store them in plain old files on the same file system as the application, and when the application starts up, it will read that data into memory.

Comment: OK, so disk-backed data loaded into a local memory cache. Fine.

Comment: Appreciate your help!